# Android Galaxy S Phone - ADB Debug Bridge Trouble on Mac OSX

Tags: android, debugging, adb

Here's the issue.  I do this to get the device list:

```
./adb devices
```

And I get this:

```
List of devices attached
```

with no returned devices.  If I run the emulator, that shows on the above list, but still no physical device.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S Fasciate (Verizon model) on a MacBook running OS 10.5.

I am connecting through a powered USB hub as was advised on a different message board (I can find the source if anyone's interested).  This also does not work when I connect directly.

According to the Mac System Profiler, the device is plugged in:

```
SAMSUNG_Android:

Product ID: 0x681c
Vendor ID:  0x04e8  (Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.)
Version:    2.23
Serial Number:  I500874368c4
Speed:  Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer:   SAMSUNG
Location ID:    0xfd140000
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA):  96
```

I am able to mount the SD drive and have even successfully used two different apps that tether an internet connection via the USB cable, so I can safely assume that the computer can properly interact with the device.

Yet for some reason, it does not show up as a device that I can debug.

(And yes, I've turned on "USB Debugging" on the phone - and even tried restarting the phone.)

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

It was EasyTether!

I installed EasyTether at some point and it was interfering with this even after I thought I uninstalled it.

Here's the solution from the EasyTether website:

> ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the
>   attached device after installing
>   EasyTether driver. Use
>   kextload/kextunload to unload from
>   memory the EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
>   kernel extension manually. It is in
>   /System/Library/Extensions/

Once again, thank you everybody for helping with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, this is a tricky one, if its anything like the other galaxy s phones, they aren't very easy to connect to a computer. I don't want to be a nay sayer but I don't see the drivers you need available for macintosh.

For example this flashing guide: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Samsung_Fascinate:_Rooting uses the adb bridge but the correct drivers are only provided for windows. The thing is it will recognise your phone as a samsung_android but thats not actually the proper driver. its just information about the device.

Try it out on a windows pc with the windows drivers and I think you'll find my suspicions confirmed.

Comment: According to the Android Developer's site, there is no need to configure anything for OS X because "it will just work" (except when it doesn't).  I don't have a Windows PC to test on, but I could try this on a Linux PC.  Do you think it's worth the trouble to see if this works?

Comment: FWIW, i debug my galaxy S from 10.6 without any problems, and without any specific drivers being installed.

Comment: Plus, as mentioned, I am having no trouble connecting - I can mount the SD drive and even tether internet over USB (which uses the debugging mode), so it seems like this is something more related to adb or the phone.

Comment: Thanks superfell.  That's hopeful at least that there's a solution.  I wonder if the issue with 10.5 although I have not found anything to support that idea.

Comment: @superfell really? thats interesting. I had to have very specific drivers for my samsung to work in adb... which galaxy s do you have? cause theres so many different models! :p

Comment: its worth mentioning actually that every samsung model will be different. i have an i5700 which is quite problematic to connect. its probably important to know which model galaxy s that superfell has before making assumptions that it will work.

Comment: Good point.  @superfell: Are you using the Verizon Fascinate?

Comment: I'm using a Vibrant on T-Mobile

Comment: @jeffp Found a driver package for your phone for mac here: http://sterlingcobb.com/fascinate.rar  try downloading the driver and set it up. hopefully it should be recognised in adb after that. All the instructions to install the drivers are on the page here: http://sterlingcobb.com/archives/21

Comment: its a rooting guide btw so just do the driver install part. :) hope that helps. rooting guides usually give pretty good way to get connected to adb on your phone.

Comment: Thank you @Code Novitiate.  That should work, except since the device is not recognized it will fail at ./adb push and give "error: device not found".  That said, I'm going to try to re-install the SDK just in case that somehow fixes something.  This is at least a proof-of-concept that this SHOULD work with the Fascinate phone on a mac without any special drivers.

Comment: If you get prompted as to what to do when you plug your device in, pick charging only, that might help you out.

Comment: Thank you everybody for being so helpful with this.  I finally found something that works.  It is an app that will configure the ability to run adb wirelessly over tcpip and it works so smoothly.  (requires root): http://www.appbrain.com/app/adbwireless-(widget-version)/siir.es.adbWireless

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution.  I am able to connect to the Fascinate wirelessly using this app:
http://www.appbrain.com/app/adbwireless-(widget-version)/siir.es.adbWireless

I am rooted using Z4 and the whole setup is very simple.  Once rooted and running the adbWireless app I enter the connect command provided by the app and that's it.  The device is now treated as-if it's plugged in via USB and I can send apps to it over the debug bridge.

I appreciate all of the helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem and did not have EasyTether installed - you should try running:

setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1

stop adbd

start adbd

on a terminal emulator from the phone.  This turned out to be the only thing that was able to fix this issue (bought the phone off of ebay - I assume that whoever owned it before me had set it to wirelessly connect to his computer).

Check out [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) for more info