# Trying to record voice in android but getting error

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am trying to record voice in android emulator (android 4.1).

But I when I press the button to start recording then it immediately return from the function and executes next line that logs a message saying "Recorded".

Then, I press the stop button and in Logcat message appears that media recorder went away with unhandled events.

If I again press the button to start recording then I get an error message saying FATAL SIGNAL 11. And I dont know how to access the SD card to see if the file is created or not.

Below is the logCat code that I used from a tutorial:

}

```
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    try{
    recorder.prepare();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("Recorder","Recording failed");
    }
    recorder.start();
  }
  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
  }
```

The logCat is:

08-08 16:09:39.713: D/gralloc_goldfish(743): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

08-08 16:09:42.674: D/Recorder(743): Recorded

08-08 16:09:48.764: W/MediaRecorder(743): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events

08-08 16:13:01.613: A/libc(743): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 743 (xample.recorder)

Comment: Please copy and paste the Logcat text instead of image.

Comment: Do you have the needed permission(s) set in the manifest?

Comment: I am using android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions

Comment: See the second paragraph in the top rated answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254994/can-the-android-emulator-record-and-play-back-audio-using-pc-hardware  (regarding configuration of the AVD. have you done that?)

Comment: Yes I have done that but that post also mentions "Then use the [MediaRecorder API][1] to record (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)." But I am working at API level 16, the max I can go back is API level 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by resting recorder before releasing it.

```
        recorder.stop();//stop recording
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
```

Comment: I have this code on my real device but I get Error On stop recording. I think it's from my file path. would u update your whole part.

Comment: @ Kenji, I'm sorry, I do not get what you are saying. This question is closed with a working solution, it does not need update for the original issue. If you are dealing with different scenario and error, then you should ask separate question. Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871421/trying-to-record-audio-but-getting-message-mediarecorder-went-away-with-unhandl/), it has multiple answers.

Answer (score 1):

Each time create a new instance of recorder and you wont get any error.

`recorder.stop();`
`recorder.release();`
`recorder=null;`

And let the following be the first line in your startRecording() method-

`recorder=new MediaRecorder();`

For more info-http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html