# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android

15% of times that I stop recording video, app stops wich Fatal signal 11.

```
videoRecorder.stop();//video recorder is MediaRecorder object
videoRecorder.release();                

if (camera != null) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
    camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860): backtrace:
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #00  pc 00061278 
>   /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::**MediaRecorder::stop()**+3)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #01  pc 0001ac4d 
>   /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #02  pc 0001dc4c 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #03  pc 0004e113 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*,
>   Method const*, Thread*)+398)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #04  pc 00027060 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #05  pc 0002e010 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #06  pc 0002b6bc 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*,
>   JValue*)+184)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #07  pc 0006053f 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*,
>   bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #08  pc 00060563 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*,
>   JValue*, ...)+20)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #09  pc 00055253 
>   /system/lib/libdvm.so
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #10  pc 0000d208 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
>
> 04-04 22:55:16.907: D/CrashAnrDetector(4860):     #11  pc 0000d3a4 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: MediaRecorder is very picky about the order of operations to the point that you can't even stop() twice in a row; Make sure you aren't calling each function more than once until you reset() or recreate it. Log every call. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11863488/738196